# Parse.com: Querying object items in array collection

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform, querying

Let's say I have a Parse class "Pages" with a column "index" and a row that contains the following value for index:

```
{
    "date": "2016-05-14",
    "tags": [
        {
            "score": 12,
            "name": "Taekwondo"
        }, {
            "score": 15,
            "name": "Jazz"
        }, {
            "score": 22,
            "name": "Yoga"
        }, {
            "score": 8,
            "name": "Meditation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ho would I query for results with a tag named "Jazz" using the REST API and curl?
There's no word about querying for object fields in arrays of objects in the parse.com REST API documentation.

In a mongodb there is the concept of $elemMatch but obviously the parse.com layer does not support it?

```
db.index.Pages.find({ 
    index: {
        tags: { 
            $elemMatch: { name: 'Jazz' }
        }          
    }  
});
```

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Comment: I moved on to another stack (years ago), maybe this ist an anti-pattern in parse?